# Syntax Error on my php script

Tags: php

I  am getting this error message when run the code below. Below is the code that is giving me error messages. This is the error message

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\jq\fines\admin\portal.php on line 218
```

**My code:**

```
<body class="easyui-layout">
<div region="north" class="title" border="false" style="height:40px;">
Client Services Admin Portal 
</div>
<div region="center" border="false">
<div id="pp" style="position:relative">
<div style="width:30%;">
<div title="Time" style="text-align:center;background:#f3eeaf;height:170px;padding:5px;">
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="100" height="100">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.respectsoft.com/onlineclock/analog.swf">
<param name=quality value=high>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<embed src="http://www.respectsoft.com/onlineclock/analog.swf" width="100" height="100" quality=high pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent"></embed>
</object>
</div>
<div title="Current Users Logged On" collapsible="true"  closable="false" style="height:250px;padding:3px;">
<center>
<?php require_once "fines/admin/usersloggedon.php"; ?>  
</center>
</div>
</div>
<div style="width:70%;">
<div title="Search for receipt"  closable="false" style="height:170px;padding:10px;">
<center>
<form action="" method="post" id="receiptnumSearch">
<input type="hidden" name="check" value="submitted">
<input class="easyui-searchbox" style="width:200px" name="receiptnum" data-options="prompt:'',searcher:doReceiptSearch">
</form>
  <br/>
<div style="background-color:#3FF; height:1px">&nbsp;</div><br/>
<?php 
require_once"functions.php";
if($_POST['check']=='submitted')//open1
{
//checking for errors 
$receiptnum=trim($_POST['receiptnum']);
if($receiptnum=='')//open
{
//System error
echo SysError('Search field empty', 'index.php?t='.urlencode(base64_encode("admin_fins")).'&o='.md5(date('Y-m-d : t')).'');
die();

}//closed
elseif(!empty($receiptnum))//open
{                       
?><table class='tablestyle2' width=95% cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0>
<tr valign=top>
<td ><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class='tablestyle_inner'>
<tr>  
<td width="40%" class='tableheader' height="25">Paid From Library</td>
<td width="30%" class='tableheader'>Patron Name</td><td width="30%" class='tableheader'>Receipt Number</td>
 </tr>
<?php
$db1w = new PDO('mysql:host=10.40.254.229;dbname=koha_msulibrary;charset=utf8', 'root', 'philly');
$gt_r=$db1w->query("SELECT * FROM fine, borrowers,branch_libs where borrowers.cardnumber=fine.cardnumber AND branch_libs.brunchid=fine.brunchid AND fine.receiptNum='$receiptnum' LIMIT 0,1");
$gt_r_results=$gt_r->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
echo'
<tr>  
<td class=\'label\' height="25" align="center">'.$gt_r_results['branch_name'].'</td>
<td class=\'label\' align="center">'.ucwords(strtolower($gt_r_results['firstname'].' '.$gt_r_results['surname'])).'</td>
<td class=\'label\' align="center"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.msu.ac.zw/libraries/jq/fines/receipt.php?invoice='.base64_encode('invoce_view').'&t='.base64_encode($gt_r_results['receiptNum']).'">'.$gt_r_results['receiptNum'].'</a></td>
</tr>';
  ?>
</table></td></tr></table>
<?
}//closed

}//closed
?>
</center>
</div>
<div title="Library Fines Statistics" closable="false" style="height:250px;text-align:center;">
<center>
<br/><form action="" id="date_range" method="post"><table width="70%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="39%"><input type="hidden" name="date_r" value="date_r"><input name="data1" class="easyui-datebox" value="Start Date" width="200px"></input></td>
<td width="37%"><input name="data2" class="easyui-datebox" value="End Date" width="200px"></input></td>
<td width="24%"><a href="javascript:doViewFines()" class="easyui-linkbutton" plain="true">View Fines</a></td>
  </tr>
</table></form>
<br/>
<?php
 $data1=$_POST['data1'];
$data2=$_POST['data2'];
$date_r=$_POST['date_r'];
$dat=date('Y-m-d');
$da_1=strtotime($data1);
$data_=date('Y-m-d',$da_1);
//$da_2=strtotime($data2_);
//$data2=date('Y-m-d',$da_2);

//checking if date is real date
if((!isRealDate($data1) or !isRealDate($data2) or $dat < $data_ ) and $date_r=='date_r')
{
echo SysError('Incorrect date range', 'index.php?t='.urlencode(base64_encode("admin_fins")).'&o='.md5(date('Y-m-d : t')).'');
die();
}
//end of check
else{
?>
<table width=95% height="125" cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 class='tablestyle2'>
<tr valign=top><td ><table width="100%" height="122" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class='tablestyle_inner'> <tr>   <td width="50%" class='tableheader' height="19">Branch Library</td> <td width="50%" class='tableheader'>
<?php
 if($date_r=='date_r') 
{
echo 'Fine collected between '.$data1.' and '.$data2;
}
else
{
echo 'Fines Collected to Date';
}
?></td>
</tr>
<tr>  
<td class='label' height="12" >Batanai Library</td>
<td class='label' style="padding-left:10px">
<?php   //checking if the date is real
if($date_r!='date_r')
{
echo GETbranchlibs('2');
}
elseif($date_r=='date_r')
{
echo  GetBrunchLibsRange($data1,$data2,'2');
}
?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='label' height="6">GSBL</td>
<td class='label' style="padding-left:10px">
<?php
if($date_r!='date_r')
{
echo GETbranchlibs('3');
} 
elseif($date_r=='date_r')
{
echo  GetBrunchLibsRange($data1,$data2,'3');
}
?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='label' height="3" >Law Library</td>
<td class='label' style="padding-left:10px"><?php
if($date_r!='date_r')
{
echo GETbranchlibs('4');
}
elseif($date_r=='date_r')
{
echo  GetBrunchLibsRange($data1,$data2,'4');
}
?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='label' height="3" >Main Library</td>
<td class='label' style="padding-left:10px"><?php 
if($date_r!='date_r')
{
echo GETbranchlibs('1');
}
elseif($date_r=='date_r')
{
echo  GetBrunchLibsRange($data1,$data2,1);
}
?></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td class='label' height="2" >Total</td>
<td class='label' style="padding-left:10px; font-weight:bold;"><u><?php 
if($date_r!='date_r')
{
echo GETbranchlibs('0');
}
elseif($date_r=='date_r')
{
echo  GetBrunchLibsRange($data1,$data2,'0');
}

}
?></u></td>
</tr>
</table></td></tr></table></center>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Unexpected end of file" means that you have more curly-brace-open than you have curly-brace-close most of the time. If you properly format the code, you can probably see where it starts mismatching pretty easily.

Comment: This is basic stuff getting something to parse. Comment out all of it then add a bit back at a time.

Comment: Error: code formatting not found.

Comment: @ialarmedalien wat, how would this be a duplicate, the code is totaly different.

Comment: @Azrael it's the same basic compilation error -- usually means a missing close brace at the end of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote somewhere in there

```
<? instead of <?php
```

So just change that and it will work. Tested on http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php

Comment: shorttags, however it is recommended to use the normal `<?php` tags this has nothing to do with OP's problem

Comment: Yes it does have something to do with the problem. With <? it does not work, with <?php it does. Try it yourself if you don't believe it.

Comment: Please flag the answer as correct for your question.

Comment: If you want to use <? as open tag you need to add "short_open_tag=On" to the php.ini file.